# Unable to install Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm typing

```
mar@Android-4311:~$ sudo apt-get install vulkan-sdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vulkan-sdk

always E: Unable to locate package vulkan-sdk
```

I don't know what I must to do?

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)

```
wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-focal.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-focal.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
```

Source: [LunarG docs](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.198.0/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html)

---

Pardon the duplicated answer, but I wanted to post the link as a comment, but don't have enough reputation yet :)

Answer (score 1):

There are repositories for 2 LTS versions and these 2 lines are mandatory before `apt install` works

- To add the key for the repository:

  ```
  wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  ```
- either Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver):

  ```
  sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-bionic.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-bionic.list
  ```
- or Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa):

  ```
  sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-focal.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-focal.list
  ```

and then ...

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
```

Comment: How does this work for 21.10? I tried to do it the same way but it says that apt-key is deprecated.